# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'S'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

What's wrong with following query?

```
sqlcmd -S demuck1ak23\TASKMANAPP -U TaskManagementReadonlyuser 
       -P readonly123 -d Adventureworks2012 
       -Q "SELECT taskcategory,initialprepac,currentprepac FROM [dbo].[v_tasks]" 
       -o C:\SQLLOADER\Employees.txt
```

Comment: I think the issue is the `\ ` in the file paths -- put them in quotes or use `\\ `  (backslash is hard - even getting this answer to look right took about 6 edits)

Comment: You're running this from Management Studio, right? [`sqlcmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility) is a command-line tool and you can't execute this whole command as a query.

Comment: hello mat, kindly suggest me any way out for this even to run the statement, I create a command that uses the -i switch to call the myscript.sql file,  sqlcmd -S demuck1ak23\TASKMAN -U TaskManagementReadonlyuser -P readonly123 -i "C:\SQLLOADER\myscript.sql"  , i am getting the same syntax error.

Comment: The problem isn't the query `"SELECT taskcategory..."`. The problem is that you're seemingly trying to run sqlcmd.exe from a query-window in Management Studio. You need to run it from command-line [(CMD.EXE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe). Follow the link in my previous comment.